# matplotlib set xticks & work with SQL

Tags: matplotlib

In my bar chart, I need to set my `xticks` with an hour format like this:

```
6:00, 7:00, 8:00......
```

The data I used to make the chart comes from a `MySQL` database and I used `TimeStamp` in the database table. Right now the `xticks` are like this:

```
6, 7, 8......
```

I don't know how to change it in the way I want.

```
`query = """select HOUR(TimeStamp) AS Hour, SUM(Pac/12) As Pac FROM SolarData WHERE `TimeStamp` >= CURDATE() AND `TimeStamp` < CURDATE()+1 GROUP BY HOUR(TimeStamp);""";`
```

Addition: `TimeStamp` doesn't get created at the same time every day. I would prefer if the `x-axis` could be labeled as this image below (to be the same everyday):

[image]

But if I made `x-axis` like this, considering the way I made the query, there might be a potential problem: `HOUR(TimeStamp)` is an `INT` data type and the `x-axis` in the image are labeled with `STRING` data type... as long as I understand. I tried with this query below, but I still didn't get around with the data type conflict problem. Instead of setting the `xticks`, I tried to reformat `TimeStamp` to make it like:

```
6:00,7:00,8:00,9:00...
```

instead of:

```
6,7,8,9....
```

`'%H:%00'` will make `TimeStamp` unable to work with the `plt.bar()` command at the bottom because it changes the data format of `TimeStamp`

```
`select DATE_FORMAT(TimeStamp, '%H:%00') AS Hour, SUM(Pac/12) As Pac FROM SolarData WHERE `TimeStamp` >= CURDATE()-1 AND `TimeStamp` < CURDATE() GROUP BY HOUR(TimeStamp);`

barchart = plt.bar(TimeStamp, Pac, align='center', width=0.20, color='#FFCC33')
```

Basically, is there any way I can personalize `xticks` while it's able to work with `TimeStamp`?